Proxy-VAR derivation in Gertler & Karadi (2015) paper
I'm reading on proxy VARs and I've come across a nice exposition in Gertler and Karadi's paper from 2015 titled "Monetary Policy Surprises, Credit Costs and
Economic Activity" on page 52, footnote 4.

I've been dealing with this derivation for a couple of days and it still isn't clear how the author came to the equations for $$Q$$ and $$ s_{12}*s_{12}'$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
